# Find files until a number and do an operation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have a number of files named `note1.txt, note2.txt, note3.txt, ....` to say until `note100.txt`. I would like to copy only files until `note50.txt` to a different folder. How to achieve this in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way (IMHO) would be to use shell expansions:

```
$ cp note{1..50}.txt /path/to/target
```

Comment: never knew it would be as simple as `{1..50}` :)